# Help with different probabilities method to solve cards problem

Tags: probability, combinations, poker

I would like to calculate the probability of getting two cards but they cant be Kings for example. 
I thought it could be solved by getting C(48,2) which is 1128.
Which means, choose 2 of the remaining 48 cards since I excluded 4 Kings.

But I saw a solution where it gets C(12,2) x C(4,1) x C(4,1) = 1056. 
Which means get two cards from 12 (13 excluding King) times 4 (kinds of the first card) times 4 (kinds of the second card).

Why these two results are not the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second solution assumes that the face values of the two cards are different, while the first solution doesn't.  $C(12,2)$ says "pick two face values out of the pool of $A$ through $Q$."  But they must be different.

Add back in the $12$ pairs (with $6$ combinations apiece) and you get the same answer.